# Encryption of entire database or selected tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I m bit new to this field of DBA i wanted to know is there any codes available to encrypt the entire database as we have a huge database maintained in sqlserver 2005 . 
I know that it is not safe to encrypt the entire database but we ha such kind of requirement moreover the in the application end they don't want to encrypt it.
i want the process to be as the data comes through the application end into the database it should be encrypted and stored and while retrieving the data it must be decrypted with a certificate/key as provided and shown. I don't want to use any 3rd party tools as it has been instructed.
i searched through the net and found that we can encrypt columns and stored procedure through asymmetric/symmetric key but i need to encrypt the entire database(selected tables is also ok) can you all help me in that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it in 2005, you would need to redefine all (or most) of your tables to take encrypted data (varbinary) and then you'd lose the ability to do searches and comparisions and a whole heap of other stuff.

For 2008 there is Transparent Data(base) Encryption, which encrypts at the file level (when SQL server writes data) no changes required to your applications.

Search for SQL Server TDE and have a look around.

Comment: TDE is easy to use and transparent to your database applications. Programmers are not required to change their codes, etc. But dba's should take care of encryption keys, etc for backup restores, etc.